# Mongoose find query returns default value to a field which was recently added

Tags: mongoose

```
var cursor = this.find(query).select({
"alias": 1,
"To": 1,
"city": 1,
"state": 1,
"cdr": 1,
"RecordUrl": 1,
"From": 1,
"Digits": 1,
"bundle": 1,
"callResult": 1,
"advivrDuration": 1,
"connectDuration": 1,
"Duration": 1,
"StartTime": 1,
"comment": 1,
"zipcode": 1,
}).sort({ StartTimeNumberEST: -1 }).hint({ StartTimeNumberEST: 1 }).lean().cursor();
```

Previously it was this query now its the below one

```
var cursor = this.find(query).select({
"alias": 1,
"To": 1,
"city": 1,
"state": 1,
"cdr": 1,
"RecordUrl": 1,
"From": 1,
"Digits": 1,
"bundle": 1,
"callResult": 1,
"advivrDuration": 1,
"connectDuration": 1,
"Duration": 1,
"StartTime": 1,
"comment": 1,
"zipcode": 1,
"cpa": 1
}).sort({ StartTimeNumberEST: -1 }).hint({ StartTimeNumberEST: 1 }).lean().cursor();
```

The problem m facing is after adding cpa to be added to data cpa is always the default value
it does not send me the exact value in the database
pretty new to mongo db anybody.

Schema:

```
var Trans = new Mongoose.Schema({
_id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
transaction_id: { type: String },
corrects_transaction_id: { type: String },
original_order_id: { type: String },
complete_call_id: { type: String },
start_time_local: { type: Date },
start_time_xml: { type: Date },
StartTime: { type: String },
StartTimeNumberEST: { type: SchemaTypes.Long, min: 0, default: 0 },
StartTimeHour: { type: Number },
StartTimeDay: { type: String },
AnswerTime: { type: Date },
CustomeIvrTime: { type: Date },
EndTime: { type: Date },
corrected_at: { type: String },
offer: { type: String },
alias: { type: String },
tempoffer: { type: String },
cdr: { type: String },
bundle: { type: String },
From: { type: String },
To: { type: String },
callPromo: { type: String },
mobile: { type: String },
routed_to_number: { type: String },
city: { type: String },
state: { type: String },
zipcode: { type: String },
Digits: { type: String },
Duration: { type: Number },
connectDuration: { type: Number, default: 0 },
customivrDuration: { type: Number },
advivrDuration: { type: Number, default: 0 },
callResult: { type: String },
allCallResult: { type: String },
RecordingID: { type: String },
RecordUrl: { type: String },
cpa: { type: Number, default: 0 },
TotalCost: { type: Number },
BillDuration: { type: Number },
BillRate: { type: Number },
HangupCause: { type: String },
Direction: { type: String },
CallStatus: { type: String },
Event: { type: String },
media_type: { type: String },
transcription: { type: String },
affiliate_payout_localized: { type: String },
matching_affiliate_payout_policies: { type: String },
payout_conditions: { type: String },
opt_in_SMS: { type: Number },
transfer_from_type: { type: String },
comment: { type: String },
```

});

Comment: Show your schema. It's likely overridden with a virtual or something similar.

Comment: Sure i updated the schema above